# YouTube API not showing data when in "some" date ranges

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

My problem has started when I've changed the date in the GET request to the YouTube API. I am currently trying to view likes, dislikes, views, averageWatchTime and subscribersGained using the:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3D{channel_id}&start-date=2017-01-19&end-date=2017-01-26&metrics=likes%2Cdislikes%2CaverageViewDuration%2Cviews%2CsubscribersGained&access_token={access_token}
```

The JSON response I get looks like:

```
{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "likes",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "dislikes",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "averageViewDuration",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "views",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "subscribersGained",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ]
}
```

However, If I use the same query as above but set the date to a few months earlier such as:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3D{channel_id}&start-date=2016-08-19&end-date=2017-01-26&metrics=likes%2Cdislikes%2CaverageViewDuration%2Cviews%2CsubscribersGained&access_token={access_token}
```

I get the same JSON except containing the relevant information related to my query (The actual statistics)

```
{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "likes",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "dislikes",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "averageViewDuration",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "views",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "subscribersGained",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.0,
   0.0
  ]
 ]
}
```

I'm unsure to why this doesn't give me results for the first query. Even if the data is all 0s (If that is the reason). I'm trying to view the channel statistics for the past week but unfortunately because of this I cannot see them.

Why does the rows object not appear for the first query but appears for the second?

Comment: I think it is a natural behavior of the response. I also tried it and get the same result for the first query : `null` response. But when I tried expanding the date range, I've got a value in two of my metric (views,like), a zero for dislike. Maybe the explanation is that in the first query, as a group there is zero activities (metrics you want to get) to present on the other hand in the second query to know what metric has a value, the response return a zero value on other metric. I hope this information helps.

Comment: I agree. Because there are no metrics results available (All 0) it returns nothing